# Solving an ODE with singular point: is this correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

This is from a text book by Tsai Tai-Peng "Lectures on Navier-Stokes Equations", page 148 if anyone wants to read. But I am only asking about how to solve this ODE,

$$(1-t^2) L'' +2L+LL' = 0, \quad t\in(-1,1)\\L(-1)=L(1)=0.$$
The author begins by noticing that $(1-t^2)$ is a solution to the linear problem (just deleting the $LL'$ term)
$$ (1-t^2) L'' +2L = 0.$$
"Therefore", as a kind of variation of parameters method, he decides to set
$$ L(t) \overset{\Delta}=u(t)(1-t^2).$$
Apparently, it follows that $u$ solves
$$ u' + \frac{u^2}2 = 0?$$

I really can't prove this, and must be going crazy. If you want some scratch work to see:

\begin{align} L &= (1-t^2)u\\ L’ &= (1-t^2)u’ -2tu\\
L’’ &= (1-t^2)u’’ - 2tu’ - 2tu’ - 2u\\
&= (1-t^2)u’’ - 4tu’ - 2u 
\end{align}
divide L equation by $1-t^2$,
\begin{align}
(1-t^2)u’’ - 4tu’ - 2u + 2u + u L’ &= 0\\
(1-t^2)u’’ - 4tu’ 
            + u[ (1-t^2)u’ -2tu ]&=0
\end{align}

Any pointers? This is apparently from [the thesis of the author](https://search.proquest.com/docview/304449952) Tsai Tai-Peng but I don't have access to it at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
(1-t^2)u’’ - 4tu’ 
            + u[ (1-t^2)u’ -2tu ]&=0
\end{align}$$
You are almost there, Calvin, because the author split the original differential equation into  two differential equations that are equivalents for some value of the constant of integration:
$$(1-t^2)(u''+uu')=0 \tag 1$$
And also :
$$-4tu'-2tu^2=0 \implies u'+\dfrac {u^2}2=0  \tag 2$$

These two equations are equivalents I guess if you equate the costant to zero since first equation gives after integration:
$$(1-t^2)(u''+uu')=0 \tag 1$$
$$u''+uu'=0 $$
$$u'+\dfrac {u^2}2=C$$
Set $c=0$. Then the author deduces that:
$$u(t)=\dfrac 2 {t-a}$$
where $a$ is a constant.

---

**Another method:**

You can also use substitution method :
$$\begin{align}
(1-t^2)u’’ - 4tu’ 
            + u[ (1-t^2)u’ -2tu ]&=0
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
(1-t^2)(u’’+uu') - 4t(u’+\dfrac {u^2}2) &=0
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
(1-t^2)z' - 4tz &=0
\end{align}$$
Where $z=u'+\dfrac {u^2}{2}$

You can choose $z=0 \implies u'+\dfrac {u^2}2=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can he just split the ODE like that, is this some sort of ansatz..?

Comment: You're welcome. It's consistent thats the most important. You can't do that with all differential equation but here it works fine. @CalvinKhor

Comment: You can also use substitution method I added some lines @CalvinKhor

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I think I understand. So this constructs one solution to the L equation, right? Is this a unique solution?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes thats right you can also solve the first DE in z and see what you get. I dindt check uniqueness. @CalvinKhor

Comment: Thank you very much. A last small question, I would like to brush up on ODE theory, do you know good references for some basic theory like maximal interval of existence, continuous dependence on initial data, and ODEs with singular points? I know Coddington and Levinson is a standard reference but I found it hard to read

Comment: I think that Diprima Boyce book (
Elementary Differential Equations) is easier for learning differential equations. More into pratics . @CalvinKhor You can read Coddington after Boyce maybe it will be easier then.

Comment: Thanks again! Have a great day and I wish you the best of health

Comment: Thank you . I wish you the best too. Take care. @CalvinKhor